# How to update a function's value once it's been called in golang

Tags: dictionary, go, recursion, mapping

I am working on a system where I have to limit concurrent connections from a particular IP. Once a connection is made, some steps are performed and then it is dropped so that other connections can be made. Below is the code where I am updating the value of a particular variable.

Link for code - http://tpcg.io/_SQZEEX

```
package main

import "fmt"


var addresses = make([]string, 0)
func count(rAddr string, slice *[]string) map[string]int {
    dict := make(map[string]int)
    *slice = append(*slice, rAddr)
    for _, a := range *slice {
    dict[a]++

    }
    return dict
}

func listen() int {

    var rAddr string
    rAddr = "1.1.1.2"
    number_of_addresses:=count(rAddr ,&addresses)
    var v int
    for k, v := range number_of_addresses {

    fmt.Println(k, "value is", v)

        if (v > 0) {
            v--
            fmt.Println(k, "decreased value is", v)
        }


    }
    return v
}


func main() {

    listen()
    listen()

}
```

Upon calling the function again, the values are not refreshing for the "v" variable and the output is as below

```
1.1.1.2 value is 1
1.1.1.2 decreased value is 0
1.1.1.2 value is 2
1.1.1.2 decreased value is 1
```

Expected output:

```
1.1.1.2 value is 1
1.1.1.2 decreased value is 0
1.1.1.2 value is 1
1.1.1.2 decreased value is 0
```

What could I do so that the value is updated each time it is decreased. I understand that the value is refreshed but not sent back to the count function. How can this be achieved

Comment: Include the code in the question

Comment: @BurakSerdar Added the code in the question

Comment: @SanjayKumar You are duplicating the values in the slice right? `[1.1.1.2 1.1.1.2]` would the value of `addresses` after second call to `listen()`, what else do you expect?

Comment: use a `map` not a `slice` to store your IP addresses. Much easier to lookup specific IP's and/or update the concurrent count. Also since you describe a concurrent usage pattern, any variables used to audit usage volume should have lock synchronization to avoid race conditions.

Comment: @colm.anseo i am converting the address to string. how do i change it back to map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments, refactor to track IP addresses via a `map` i.e. a `map[string]int` to track usage.

A basic implementation to get you started:

```
// track unique addresses via a map:
// - key:   string of the IP address
// - value: usage count
var (
    usageMap = make(map[string]int) //
    l        sync.Mutex             // ensure concurrent access to map is synchronized
)

func modifyAddr(addr string, delta int) int {
    l.Lock()
    defer l.Unlock()

    usageMap[addr] += delta

    return usageMap[addr]
}

func incAddr(addr string) int { return modifyAddr(addr, 1) }
func decAddr(addr string) int { return modifyAddr(addr, -1) }
```

and to use:

```
const maxConcurrentUsage = 20

func listen() {

    rAddr := "1.1.1.2"

    usage := incAddr(rAddr)
    defer decAddr(rAddr)

    if usage > maxConcurrentUsage {
        log.Printf("maximum concurrent usage exceeded (%d) for address: %q", maxConcurrentUsage, rAddr)
        return
    }

    // handler logic goes here
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Jvx8l4F9OE8

Comment: Thanks @colm.anseo. But I am getting addr like this.
rAddr := conn.RemoteAddr()
And then using " if addr, ok := conn.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr); ok {
  strrAddr := addr.IP.String()"

Comment: Use: `rAddr := conn.RemoteAddr().String()` to get the string representation. This will include a trailing `:<portnumer>` - but that's relatively easy to remove.